# Navigation controller not displaying back button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a profile that is embedded in a navigation controller. When I create a segue that goes to another view controller (also embedded in a navigation controller), I get the screen below. I used to seeing the back button that, in this case, would say "< Profile" but all I see is a blank nav bar with no back button, SOS!

Can anybody help me fix this issue? I can't seem to find any help!

This is the code I have written for the segue to go from the profile view controller to the followers view controller, which is the one with the blank nav bar.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFollowers" {
        var profileVC: FollowersViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FollowersViewController
        profileVC.followers = true

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Comment: Check if the view controller has a `title`. That is the text that is shown on the back button when the child view controller is visible. If that text is `nil` there will be no back button. [Here is the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088534/navigation-controller-not-displaying-back-button-when-same-class-is-reused)

Answer (score 0):

> Are you setting `hidesBackButton = YES` or `backBarButtonItem = nil` in
>   `profileVC`, or does it have a different leftBarButtonItem
>   defined?

Have you remove `back` via programmatically please remove those code.

**EDITED**

Following code returns how many controllers into `UINavigationController` please check it out it's greater then `0` or not.

```
var stack = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array
```

May this helps lot.

Comment: There has been no code added to remove or modify the back button in any way.

Comment: I think your navigation controller can't push next controller that's why not display.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFollowers" {
//Try getting the navigation controller first as 
var navVc = segue.destination as UINavigationViewContrller
//than
var profileVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! FollowersViewController
//        var profileVC: FollowersViewController = //segue.destinationViewController as! FollowersViewController
 //       profileVC.followers = true

    }

}
```

Comment: While a "code only" answer may perfectly solve the problem stated in the question, it is usually a good thing to provide some context to the code (what was the OP doing wrong, how your code solves the problem, ...)